# Cancel a stripe subscription after at a specific date

Tags: stripe-payments

I integrated stripe using php and I now want to set a `cancel_at` date for every created subscription. This cancellation date depends on the plan that is selected. I followed the steps described in this tutorial https://phppot.com/php/manage-recurring-payments-using-stripe-billing-in-php/ , but here they don't choose a `cancel_at` date upon creating the subscription. So how can I do that ?
I prefer to set this expiry date after the subscription is created  so that I keep the exact same structure as described in the tutorial. But I wonder where can I do that ? and how ? should I set the date in one of the webhooks handling sections for example in customer.subscription.created
or on the success.php page ?

and the code would we like this ? :

```
$stripe->subscriptions->update(
 'sub_xxxxx',
 ['cancel_at' =>'10/10/2021']
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply the `cancel_at` field when creating a Subscription. It doesn't make sense to update the Subscription with the field *after* you create it because that would result in unnecessary API calls.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-cancel_at

But if you wish to, you can. Yes, you can also listen to `customer.susbcription.created` webhook event to update the Subscription's parameters.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.created

Comment: Thank You ! I have already written all the code in the tutorial that I followed, so can you tell me where exactly should I add the ```cancel_at``` field while creating a subscription ? because I can't figure out the exact right section of code where I should  add it.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you help me write the first method. But meanwhile I tried to execute the second method (changing cancel_at after creating the subscription) like in the following comment:

Comment: I have a plan of 38 euros/month , to cancel it in 2 months I wrote :
```$sub->cancel_at = strtotime("+2 month",  $sub->start_date); 
   $sub->save();
```
So the subscription started in 12/3/2021 at 4:36 PM and the end date in my dashboard was effectively 12/5/2021 at 4:36 PM however my next invoice will be created in Apr 12, 5:36 PM with an amount of €37.95 instead of 38 ! why ? I read about proration_behavior and billing cycle but didn't understand what are they and if they are the cause .

Comment: Again I prefer to apply the cancel_at upon subscribing but I can't find any create subscription method in the whole code !

Comment: I briefly looked through the tutorial website you linked, I think it's under `createCheckoutSession` method. As for why it's deducted 37.95 instead of 38, that's abit odd and I'm not too sure. It doesn't reflect the fees that Stripe deducts as well.

Comment: I checked that section and googled that, in fact we cannot add the subscription cancellation date in the session creation phase. so I went for listening to customer.susbcription.created . As for the example of 38, I posted a detailled question about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66621644/stripe-disable-proration if you wanna check it. Thank you again for your answer !

Comment: That's odd. Stripe's documentation states it is possible: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-cancel_at. FYI I'm referring to the latest API version, 2020-08-27.

Comment: Yes it is possible when you create a subscription directly. In this case I am cteating a subscription through the session object. So you cannot set a cancellation date from here https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create

Comment: I see, yeah, you're right. Seems like the behavior of `Subscription`, if created through `Session`, isn't consistent with creating a stand-alone `Subscription`. In that case, updated the `cancel_at` param via webhook seems like a decent approach.

Comment: Thanks ! For the 38 euros I responded to your answer on the second post.

Comment: "In that case, updated the cancel_at param via webhook seems like a decent approach",.. can you help me choose whiich webhook should I update the cancel_at field in ? basically as I've read , tracking subscriptions is best done using invoice payment succeeded event. however in my case I want to update my cancel at field at the creation of my subscription so I have two choices either I update it in the customer subscription created event webhook, or in I do a query to find the number of invoices paud by this customer for this subscription, if it is equal to 1 then this is the first payment .

Comment: and if this is the first invoice then I can update my subscription cancel_at. I'd rather go for the customer.subscription.created but what i read on the web  about how Stripe does not ensure the order in which events are received and how events should be tracked using invoice succeed made me hesitate although In my case i don't have a workflow to care about the synchronization. I just want to update my field.

Answer (score 4):

You likely want to use Subscription Schedules, rather than what's described in that tutorial, to do what you're trying to do here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#installment-plans

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already implemented it like in the tutorial. so is that wrong? or i just need to add a schedule? Honestly I prefer to just use a cancel_at if that is feasible so that I don't change my previous work a lot.

Comment: You can use `cancel_at` if you want for sure: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at

Comment: yeah but it will always cause proration for a future date. thank you anws

Comment: It will, yes.  So you can either use `cancel_at` with a proration, or use Schedules.