# Stripe Disable Proration

Tags: stripe-payments

I have two plans in my Stripe subscriptions.
The first plan is a plan of 10 euros/month until a specific date say for example it started in 10/2/2021 and I want it to end in 15/7/2021. And I want the subsriber to always pay 10 euros/month even for the last month. So I don't want any proration behaviour.
In an attempt to do this I did the following on customer.susbcription.created event [I want to update the newly created subscription] :

```
$sub->cancel_at = strtotime($my_selected_timestamp);
$sub->save();
```

The second is a plan of 38 euros/month , to cancel it in 2 months I wrote in the customer.susbcription.created event :

```
$sub->cancel_at = strtotime("+2 month",  $sub->start_date);    
$sub->save();
```

So the subscription started in 12/3/2021 at 4:36 PM and the end date in my dashboard was effectively 12/5/2021 at 4:36 PM however my next invoice will be created in Apr 12, 5:36 PM with an amount of €37.95 instead of 38 ! why ? I read about proration_behavior and tried to **update** my already existing subscription by setting this behavior to none but that didn't work.

I couldn't find any proration field in the subscription object in order to update it to none, so in an attempt to solve this issue I tried this and It worked (now I have 38 euros for my next invoice):

```
$expiry_date =   strtotime("+2 month", $sub->start_date); 
$sub->cancel_at =  strtotime("+1 hour",  $expiry_date); 
$sub->save();
```

I would like to ask you If what I did is correct or does it have any implications ??
In many previous posts, many have said that there is a way to do this using Subscription Schedules. However in my case I cannot set some accurate number of intervals because I want the same code for both plans and the second plan is cancelled at a specific date.

EDIT :
Tried this code but also didn't work:

```
  $final = strtotime("+2 month", $subscription_obj->start_date); 
      \Stripe\Subscription::update($subscription_obj->id, [
        'cancel_at' => $final,
        'proration_behavior' => 'none',
      ]
    );
     $subscription_obj->save();
```

Here's my subscription object for a plan of 12 euros/month:

````
[id] => sub_J75FZOObndggWX
    [object] => subscription
    [application_fee_percent] => 
    [billing_cycle_anchor] => 1615717329
    [billing_thresholds] => 
    [cancel_at] => 1620984129
    [cancel_at_period_end] => 
    [canceled_at] => 1615717335
    [collection_method] => charge_automatically
    [created] => 1615717329
    [current_period_end] => 1618395729
    [current_period_start] => 1615717329
    [customer] => cus_J75Fs7RnQtMBTX
    [days_until_due] => 
    [default_payment_method] => pm_1IUr5IHEWYmoXN4GjeSdn3aK
    [default_source] => 
    [default_tax_rates] => Array
        (
        )

    [discount] => 
    [ended_at] => 
    [items] => Stripe\Collection Object
        (
            [object] => list
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Stripe\SubscriptionItem Object
                        (
                            [id] => si_J75F5QEL5Gnzqf
                            [object] => subscription_item
                            [billing_thresholds] => 
                            [created] => 1615717329
                            [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                                (
                                )

                            [plan] => Stripe\Plan Object
                                (
                                    [id] => price_1IJes9HEWYmoXN4GiFeNywqa
                                    [object] => plan
                                    [active] => 1
                                    [aggregate_usage] => 
                                    [amount] => 1200
                                    [amount_decimal] => 1200
                                    [billing_scheme] => per_unit
                                    [created] => 1613048777
                                    [currency] => eur
                                    [interval] => month
                                    [interval_count] => 1
                                    [livemode] => 
                                    [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [nickname] => 
                                    [product] => prod_IvVt5EemrpxKcf
                                    [tiers_mode] => 
                                    [transform_usage] => 
                                    [trial_period_days] => 
                                    [usage_type] => licensed
                                )

                            [price] => Stripe\Price Object
                                (
                                    [id] => price_1IJes9HEWYmoXN4GiFeNywqa
                                    [object] => price
                                    [active] => 1
                                    [billing_scheme] => per_unit
                                    [created] => 1613048777
                                    [currency] => eur
                                    [livemode] => 
                                    [lookup_key] => 
                                    [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [nickname] => 
                                    [product] => prod_IvVt5EemrpxKcf
                                    [recurring] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                                        (
                                            [aggregate_usage] => 
                                            [interval] => month
                                            [interval_count] => 1
                                            [trial_period_days] => 
                                            [usage_type] => licensed
                                        )

                                    [tiers_mode] => 
                                    [transform_quantity] => 
                                    [type] => recurring
                                    [unit_amount] => 1200
                                    [unit_amount_decimal] => 1200
                                )

                            [quantity] => 1
                            [subscription] => sub_J75FZOObndggWX
                            [tax_rates] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [has_more] => 
            [total_count] => 1
            [url] => /v1/subscription_items?subscription=sub_J75FZOObndggWX
        )

    [latest_invoice] => in_1IUr5JHEWYmoXN4GTmJ3pJUZ
    [livemode] => 
    [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
        (
            [myID] => 1
        )

    [next_pending_invoice_item_invoice] => 
    [pause_collection] => 
    [pending_invoice_item_interval] => 
    [pending_setup_intent] => 
    [pending_update] => 
    [plan] => Stripe\Plan Object
        (
            [id] => price_1IJes9HEWYmoXN4GiFeNywqa
            [object] => plan
            [active] => 1
            [aggregate_usage] => 
            [amount] => 1200
            [amount_decimal] => 1200
            [billing_scheme] => per_unit
            [created] => 1613048777
            [currency] => eur
            [interval] => month
            [interval_count] => 1
            [livemode] => 
            [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                (
                )

            [nickname] => 
            [product] => prod_IvVt5EemrpxKcf
            [tiers_mode] => 
            [transform_usage] => 
            [trial_period_days] => 
            [usage_type] => licensed
        )

    [quantity] => 1
    [schedule] => 
    [start_date] => 1615717329
    [status] => active
    [transfer_data] => 
    [trial_end] => 
    [trial_start] => 
)
```
````

Comment: We were in a similar situation and concluded that need to create our own service. This is a a blog post about it - https://blog.widefix.com/stripe-plan-change-proration-service/

Answer (score 2):

Have you disabled `proration`? You have to specifically disable it:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations#preview-proration

> proration_behavior (optional)
>
> Determines how to handle prorations resulting from the billing_cycle_anchor. Valid values are create_prorations or none.
>
> Passing create_prorations will cause proration invoice items to be created when applicable. Prorations can be disabled by passing none. If no value is passed, the default is create_prorations.

As to why the next invoice is $37.95 instead of $38, likely due to proration being prorated to seconds: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations#preview-proration

> You can use this information to confirm the changes with the customer before modifying the subscription. Because Stripe prorates to the second, prorated amounts can change between the time they’re previewed and the time the update is made. To avoid this, pass in a subscription_proration_date to the invoice when you preview a change. When you update the subscription, you can pass the same date using the proration_date parameter on a subscription so that the proration is calculated at the same time.

Comment: As usual great answer ! No I didn't disable disable proration. Can you please tell me how to added to my code to see how will my lines of code change ?

Comment: For the proration date and seconds, can you tell me in my case to what should I set my date and how ? Sorry but i am new to php as well as to stripe and didn't get the idea of the proration date.

Comment: So from what I understood to solve my issue I either disbale proration on cancellation or I keep proration with an updated proration date?

Comment: In the respective `Subscription` webhook event, e.g. `customer.subscription.created`, you can update the `proration_behavior` to `none`, see https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior. Try this approach and see if your next invoice's amount is correct.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work:
`$final = strtotime("+2 month", $subscription_obj->start_date); \Stripe\Subscription::update($subscription_obj->id, ['cancel_at' => $final,'proration_behavior' => 'none',]); $subscription_obj->save(); `

Comment: Did you try on a new `Subscription`? Note that the existing invoice is not finalized until an hour or so before a charge will be attempted, so I think the value won't be updated properly yet. Could you also update your question with the `Subscription`'s object so we can see the structure?

Comment: yes I tried on the new subscription but still same behaviour . I updated my answer with a subscription of 12 euros/month. I am getting next invoice 11.98 euros.

Comment: Even when I turn on and off the prorate changes button from the dashboard, the invoice amount remains 11.98 .

Comment: Can you check the event of the invoice that has been created, i.e. `invoice.created` and see what's the body like? Is the amount, when created, also 11.98, or is it 12 and it gets updated to 11.98 during an invoice update, i.e. `invoice.updated`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for tour answers .. i did a live chat with stripe and they told me that there's isn't any way to disable the proration while setting a specific cancellation date. This proration can only be disabled if we cancel immediately or if we cancel at the end of the current period.

Comment: That's some weird behavior! Thanks for letting me know.